# Trouble accessing IEnumerable in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have following code in visual studio 2013:

```
IEnumerable<Brouwer> brouwers = Bierhalle.GetBrouwers();
```

Every Brouwer has a list of beers.

Now I need to get that list from every Brouwer, and print that list.

So I have this to print out the beers:

```
private static void PrintBieren(IEnumerable<Bier> bieren)
        {
            foreach (Bier b in bieren)
                Console.WriteLine(b.Naam + " - " + b.AlcoholPercentage);
        }
```

But how can I get that list of beers? And how can I order it by name?

I have this now but this yields an IList and I need IEnumerable:

```
IEnumerable<Bier> bieren = from b in brouwers
                select b.Bieren;
```

Comment: List<T> implements IEnumerable<T>. you do not have to convert or cast anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this to get the beers ordered by name:

```
IEnumerable<Bier> bieren = brouwers.SelectMany(b => b.Bieren)
                                   .OrderBy(bi => bi.Naam);
```

or using the query comprehension style that you have there:

```
IEnumerable<Bier> bieren = from brouwer in brouwers
                           from bier in brouwer.Bieren
                           orderby bier.Naam
                           select bier;
```

Comment: Ah didn't know I could do this with SelectMany, Great! Thanks!